# What is the default behavior of GNU cp when copying from a symbolic link?

Tags: symlink, cp, coreutils

Can someone elaborate on [this description in the official docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/cp-invocation.html#cp-invocation)?

> When copying from a symbolic link, cp normally follows the link only when not copying recursively or when --link (-l) is used.

Answer (score 2):

Say you have a symlink `foo/bar -> baz`:

```
% mkdir foo
% ln -s baz foo/bar
% tree foo
foo
└── bar -> baz

1 directory, 1 file
```

If you copy `foo/baz` directly, `cp` will follow the symlink and copy the target:

```
% cp foo/bar .
cp: cannot stat 'foo/bar': No such file or directory
```

Here, `cp` isn't reaching `foo/bar` by copying recursively, so the target file will be copied.

If, instead, you copy `foo` and tell `cp` to recurse, it will copy the symlink itself, and not the target:

```
% cp -r foo foo2
% tree foo2
foo2
└── bar -> baz

1 directory, 1 file
```

And if you try to copy recursively but also set the `-l` option, `cp` will again try to follow the symlink:

```
% cp -rl foo bar3
cp: cannot stat 'foo/bar': No such file or directory
```